# how to get the data from your php server in ionic 2 app

Tags: php, angular, ionic2

```
export class LoginPage {
```

login: {username?: string, password?: string} = {};
  submitted = false;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public userData: UserData, private menu: MenuController) { }

onLogin(form) {
    this.submitted = true;

```
if (form.valid) {
  this.userData.login(this.login.username);
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your PHP backend asynchronously via AJAX :

```
return $http.get("https://yourbackend.com/api/your_call")
    .then(function(response){
      /* Here you can process the backend response */
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

when I call the PHP server, server respond me with the json data object, i need to navigate to page, if the status is true.

```
login(){

let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let alert = this.alert.create({
            title: 'Warning',
            subTitle: 'Wrong Username or Password! Please Try Again !',
            buttons: ['OK']
            });
let loader = this.loading.create({
            content: "Checking ! Please wait...",
            duration: 1000
        });

let email = this.data.email;

let password = this.data.password;
let data = JSON.stringify({email, password});
let link = "http://"link"";


  this.http.post(link, data, {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page1);
      loader.present();
        console.log(res.json());
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      alert.present();
      });
```

}
}